# error: database "typeorm_DB" does not exist

Tags: typescript, postgresql, npm, typeorm, data-migration

I have created a Database via PSQL with the name "typeorm_DB"

```
postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" at port "5432".

\c typeorm_DB
You are now connected to database "typeorm_DB" as user "postgres".
```

if I then type in **npm start** then it comes:

Postgres : psql: FATAL: database “typeorm_DB” does not exist

---

ormconfig.json

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "test",
   "database": "typeorm_DB",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to rename the database so the name is all lowercase. Mixed case identifiers will only give you many headaches.

Comment: Thanks :-)! It works!!!